# Finding horizontal tangents to a function.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, polynomials, analytic-geometry

> Find the points at which the line tangent to the following function is horizontal $$q(x)=(x+3)^4(2x-1)^7$$

Every time I've gotten to the point of finding $x$ the numbers are all irrationally too large. I've gotten $2(2x-1)^6(x+3)^3(11x+19).$ But I do not see a way to solve from these numbers.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you show the steps you followed and the equations that you found that resulted in "too large" values of $x$, someone might be able to say something useful about that.

Comment: I just did, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Remember: the derivative of the function in $x$ is the slope of the tangent line in $x$.

Comment: @Colby Good, you calculated correctly and got very close to the answer on your own. This means we can look at what remains to do rather than what you already know.

Answer (score 2):

Hint, use product rule ( and chaining rule) for derivative:

$$
q'(x)=4(x+3)^3(2x-1)^7+14(2x-1)^6(x+3)^4= 2(x+3)^3(2x-1)^6(11x+19)
$$

So you have: $ q'(x)=0 \iff (x+3)^3(2x-1)^6(11x+19)=0$ that is factorized.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly found that $q'(x) = 2(2x-1)^6(x+3)^3(11x+19).$
Now you just need to find where $q'(x) = 0.$

The formula for $q'(x)$ may look complicated but you only need some very
simple things from it. It is the product of four terms:
$$2 \times (2x-1)^6 \times (x+3)^3 \times (11x+19).$$
Then $q'(x)=0$ exactly when at least one of those terms is zero.
Obviously $2 \neq 0$ always,
so you need to find
$$\begin{align}
x_1 \quad &\mbox{such that}\quad (2x_1-1)^6 = 0,\\
x_2 \quad &\mbox{such that}\quad (x_2+3)^3 = 0, \quad \mbox{and}\\
x_3 \quad &\mbox{such that}\quad 11x_3+19 = 0.
\end{align}$$
That is, you may have up to three different values of $x$ 
that will make $q'(x)=0.$
Notice that the only way in which you need to use the exponents here
is to confirm that they are all positive; for example,
either  $2x-1 = 0$ and therefore $(2x-1)^6 = 0$,
or  $2x-1 \neq 0$ and therefore $(2x-1)^6 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We need $q'(x)=\left((x+3)^4(2x-1)^7\right)'=0$.
$$(\ln\, q(x))'=\frac{q'(x)}{q(x)} \Rightarrow q'(x) = q(x)\cdot(\ln\, q(x))'$$
$$q'(x)=(x+3)^4(2x-1)^7\left(\frac{4}{x+3}+\frac{7\cdot 2}{2x-1}\right)=$$
$$(x+3)^3(2x-1)^6\left(4(2x-1)+14(x+3)\right)=(x+3)^3(2x-1)^6(22x+38).$$
So, there are the roots of q'(x): $-3,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{19}{11}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use factorization to find the roots:
\begin{align}
\frac{d q}{dx}
&= 4(x+3)^3 (2x-1)^7+14 (x+3)^4 (2x-1)^6
\\
&=(x+3)^3(2 x-1)^6 (4 (2x-1)+14(x+3))
\\
&=
2(11 x+19)(x+3)^3 (2x-1)^6
=0.
\end{align}